# this cod receive a file containing dates and print them. then order them, but i receive a strange output and i can't make a proper function for qsort

Tags: c, struct, output, qsort

this is the type of file the code reads

20 October 1998

1 December 2029

22 January 2002

5 January 1997

19 October 1998

just a series of dates. the read_file function should store these dates into the date struct pointer list, but i receive this strange output, once i try to convert the months into numbers(to make sorting easier)

1924802780

October

1924802780

December

1924802780

January

0

January

0

October

here first i print the converted month and then the month as it was read in the file. of course october should have been number 9

also, the second problem, the datecmp function works very nicely, but if i call the qsort function from the library i receive this warning

prova.c:127:33: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (struct date *,
struct date *)' to parameter of type 'int (* _Nonnull)(const void *, const
void *)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
qsort(list , n, sizeof(*list), datecmp);
^~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:161:22: note:
passing argument to parameter '__compar' here
int (* _Nonnull __compar)(const void *, const void *));

how am i suppose to modify the datecmp function to solve this?

thanks for the help

here's the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct date *Read_File(FILE *f, int *n)
{
    int i;
    int dim = 4;
    char month[20];
    char buf[250];
    struct date *list;

    list = malloc(dim * sizeof(*list));
        if (list == NULL) {
        (*n) = 0;
        free(list);
        return NULL;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) != NULL) {
        i = sscanf(buf, "%d %s %d", 
                &list[*n].day,  month, &list[*n].year);
        if (i < 3) {
            puts("wrong number of elements");
            return NULL;
        }

        if (!(strcmp(month, "January")))
            list[*n].month = 0;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "febrary")))
            list[*n].month = 1;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "march")))
            list[*n].month = 2;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "april")))
            list[*n].month = 3;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "may")))
            list[*n].month = 4;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "june")))
            list[*n].month = 5;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "july")))
            list[*n].month = 6;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "august")))
            list[*n].month = 7;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "september")))
            list[*n].month = 8;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "October")))
            list[*n].month = 9;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "november")))
            list[*n].month = 10;
        else if (!(strcmp(month, "December")))
            list[*n].month = 11;

        (*n) = (*n) + 1;
        printf("\n %d \n", list[i].month);
        printf("\n %s \n", month);
        if ((dim) == (*n)) {
            dim *= 2;
            list = realloc(list, dim * sizeof(*list));
        }
        if (list == NULL) {
            (*n) = 0;
            free(list);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
//int datecmp(struct data *data1, struct data *data2)
int datecmp(struct date *date1, struct date *date2)
{
    if (date1->year == date2->year) {
        if (date1->month == date2->month) {
            if (date1->day == date2->day)
                return 0;
            else if (date1->day > date2 -> day)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
                    } else if (date1->month > date2-> month) {
            return 1;
                } else {
            return -1;
            }
        } else if (date1->year > date2->year) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    struct date *list;
    int n = 0;
    int i;

    if (!(f = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
        return 0;

    if (!(list = Read_File(f, &n)))
        return 0;
    fclose(f);

    qsort(list , n, sizeof(*list), datecmp);
    free(list);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you are reading the file contents and parsing them correctly ?

Comment: Only three of the month names checked begin with an uppercase letter - the three in the example file.

Answer (score 0):

`qsort()` requires (a reference to) a comparison routine defined with both args as `const void *` and returns an `int`; for example:

```
int datecmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct date *date1 = (struct date *) a, *date2 = (struct date *) b;
    ...
    return (...);
}
```

Comment: BTW, the original code could be simplified roughly in half with use of libc services `strptime()` and `mktime()`. Let me know if you're interested in an example.

Comment: ok, but now i can't use them as struct in the function like this "if (a.year == b.year) " because a and b are const void and not struct

Comment: i need an example one how to continue the datecmp functiono

Comment: There's no need for further use of symbols `a` and `b` beyond the assignments shown. Instead of `date1` and `date2` defined as incompatible function arguments in the original posted source, they are shown here defined as locals; continue using them unchanged within your comparison routine.